# Converting tensorflow keras LSTM model into .tflite or any working format

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, keras, dl4j

I have trouble transforming my model into a one that can be deployed on android app via android-studio. My model is construed as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(70, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Then saved by .save function:

```
model.save("my.h5")
```

How can I open this model on android app?  I have seen that tflite has problems with LSTM and my attempts to load it with dl4j failed.

Comment: Did you try loading the .pb model with TensorFlow Mobile ( not TF Lite )? It supports all the ops

Comment: No. I have seen some yt comparision but i wasnt able to find any documentation on mobile or way of adding dependency.

Comment: You can follow this [blog](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-tensorflow-mobile-in-android-apps--cms-30957).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tfite converter from **tensorflow contrib(lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file( 'model.h5'))** to convert HDF5 to Tflite model.